# MKMapView add custom annotation like instagram

Tags: annotations, mkmapview, mapkit, instagram, markerclusterer

How can I custom an annotation like instagram with group and animation when zoom in https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wDa.jpg

I used JPSThumbnailAnnotation but It does not have group and very laggy, memory overflow.
I used OCMapView but It's also laggy when add a lot of annotation.

Thank you so much!